# Unable to access a value in API, and it does not return Undefined. The object that I create to store it also becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am making an API call and creating an object to store certain values. If I'm unable to access a certain value, I use optional chaining to return **undefined** so that I can set some default value in the object. However, when I try to call the value, it doesn't return undefined and it causes the object that I'm storing the value in to also be undefined. Any help is appreciated.

The Object that I'm creating

```
          homePhone: XXX
          mobilePhone: XXX
          }
```

**Here is a snippet of the API I'm accessing**
In this example I want to access the value "landlines" within the API. I am able to access it and store it within **employeeObject**

```
           "communication": {
                    "landlines": [
                        {
                            "nameCode": {
                                "codeValue": "Home Phone",
                                "shortName": "Home Phone"
                            },
                            "countryDialing": "1",
                            "areaDialing": "XXX",
                            "dialNumber": "XXX",
                            "access": "1",
                            "formattedNumber": "XXXX",
                            "itemID": "XXX"
                        }
                    ],
                    "mobiles": [
                        {
                            "nameCode": {
                                "codeValue": "Personal Cell",
                                "shortName": "Personal Mobile"
                            },
                            "countryDialing": "1",
                            "areaDialing": "XXXX",
                            "dialNumber": "XXXX",
                            "access": "1",
                            "formattedNumber": "XXXX",
                            "itemID": "XXX"
                        }
                    ],
```

In this example when landlines do not show in the API, I am not able to access it and when I try to set some default value to homePhone. It doesn't show undefined when I use Optional Chaining(?.) and when I try to return the employeeObj, it also becomes undefined.

```
          "communication": {
                    "mobiles": [
                        {
                            "nameCode": {
                                "codeValue": "Personal Cell",
                                "shortName": "Personal Mobile"
                            },
                            "countryDialing": "1",
                            "areaDialing": "XXXX",
                            "dialNumber": "XXXX",
                            "access": "1",
                            "formattedNumber": "XXXX",
                            "itemID": "XXX"
                        }
                    ],
```

This is how I accessed the value within the API

```
const homeNumber = adpEmployee.person.communication?.landlines[0].nameCode;
```

Here is a snippet of my console.log. Each row is an object within the API that I tried to access.

```
FirstName || LastName || { codeValue: 'Home Phone', shortName: 'Home Phone' }
FirstName || LastName || { codeValue: 'Home Phone', shortName: 'Home Phone' }
FirstName || LastName ||
FirstName || LastName || { codeValue: 'Home Phone', shortName: 'Home Phone' }
FirstName || LastName ||
```

Comment: Please provide a working code snippet, the description isn't clear 100%.  
Also you can always debug your code step-by-step and catch your problem.  
Learn your development tools please.